# Why doesn't my stored procedure work for all records?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a procedure which returns records correctly being sorted **desc** by JobStatus i.e.

```
3 = Current
2= Previous
1= Initial
```

i.e. record with status 3 is at top, with status 2 is after 3 and then 1. It works but I want to put another ORDERING filter too but can't figure out. The problem is the records with status 2 should be sorted according to FROM-TO Dates.

SP:

```
   SELECT serviceinfo.pk_serviceinfo_serviceinfoid, 
       serviceinfo.fk_districts_serviceinfo_initialdistrictid, 
       serviceinfo.fk_personalinfo_serviceinfo_pid, 
       serviceinfo.fk_webusers_serviceinfo_userid, 
       serviceinfo.serviceinfoentrydatetime, 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR, serviceinfo.serviceinfofromdate, 106) AS 
       ServiceInfoFromDate, 
       serviceinfodepartment, 
       CASE serviceinfo.serviceinfotodate 
         WHEN '1900-01-01' THEN '' 
         ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR, serviceinfo.serviceinfotodate, 106) 
       END                                                    ServiceInfoToDate, 
       serviceinfo.serviceinfoinitialbps, 
       serviceinfo.serviceinfoinitialdesignation, 
       serviceinfo.serviceinfoinitialbps, 
       personalinfo.personalinfoname, 
       districts.districtname, 
       serviceinfo.serviceinfojobstatus, 
       serviceinfo.serviceinfooffice, 
       serviceinfo.serviceinfocadre, 
       jobstatuses.statusname, 
       CASE serviceinfo.serviceinfoservicetype 
         WHEN 1 THEN 'Permanent' 
         WHEN 2 THEN 'Fixed Pay' 
         WHEN 3 THEN 'Contract' 
       END                                                    AS 
       ServiceInfoServiceType 
FROM   serviceinfo 
       LEFT JOIN districts 
              ON districts.pk_districts_districtid = 
                 serviceinfo.fk_districts_serviceinfo_initialdistrictid 
       INNER JOIN personalinfo 
               ON personalinfo.pk_personalinfo_id = 
                  serviceinfo.fk_personalinfo_serviceinfo_pid 
       LEFT JOIN jobstatuses 
              ON jobstatuses.pk_jobstatuses_jobstatusid = 
                 serviceinfo.serviceinfojobstatus 
       INNER JOIN web_users 
               ON web_users.userid = serviceinfo.fk_webusers_serviceinfo_userid 
WHERE  serviceinfo.fk_personalinfo_serviceinfo_pid = @pk_PersonalInfo_ID 
ORDER  BY serviceinfo.serviceinfojobstatus DESC
```

Should be arranged according to `ServiceInfoFromDate` and `ServiceInfoToDate`

```
29 Dec 2015     15 Jan 2016  Current
14 Jan 2016     06 Feb 2016  Previous
06 Feb 2016     09 Apr 2016  Previous
08 Jan 2016     13 Jan 2016  Initial
```

the reocrds with status Previous is not arranged according to date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention the exact problem you run  into, but you should try this:

```
ORDER  BY serviceinfo.serviceinfojobstatus DESC 
,         serviceinfo.serviceinfofromdate
,         serviceinfo.serviceinfotodate
```

This will sort on the source attributes, not converted to varchar, as in your query. Which I think is what's preferable.

Answer (score 1):

You can add additional query order by fields in a case statement:

```
ORDER  BY serviceinfo.serviceinfojobstatus DESC, 
case when serviceinfo.serviceinfojobstatus= 2 then ServiceInfoFromDate end
```